# PL/SQL array into refcursor to return

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm new to PL/SQL. I need to convert an array into a refcursor to return the record set. this is how SP looks like:

```
PROCEDURE EXAMPLE(p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
 TYPE COUNTRY_ARR IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(60) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
 V_COUNTRY_ARR COUNTRY_ARR; 
 BEGIN    
    V_COUNTRY_ARR(1) := 'US';
    V_COUNTRY_ARR(2) := 'AUS';
    V_COUNTRY_ARR(3) := 'NA';

    OPEN p_recordset FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(CAST(V_COUNTRY_ARR AS COUNTRY_ARR)); 
 END EXAMPLE;
```

> Gives me an error saying 'Error(86,68): PL/SQL: ORA-00902: invalid
>   datatype'

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to cast to a PL/SQL type.  That cannot be done until Oracle 12c (and, even then, the type would need to be defined in a package specification, I believe).

In Oracle 11g, you need to create `COUNTRY_ARR` as a SQL type with the `CREATE TYPE` command.  Then your cast will work.

I.e., (outside of your PL/SQL package)

```
CREATE TYPE country_arr AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(60);
```

Sorry I don't have an Oracle database handy to give more complete/exact syntax.